# How to send sms to windows phone from your android app?

Tags: android, android-intent

i am developing an android app that send sms to android base and to other mobile phone also like( windows 7 phone etc) initially for a test application i have to send sms to a windows phone attached by USB port from my eclipse emulator what should i do to send sms ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have SMS working already. All you need is to have your phones hooked up to a cellular carrier like Verizon/ATT/Sprint so you can get a phone number to send it to.

Here's a small tutorial on how to send sms from your applications that I found.
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/sending-sms-from-application/

Comment: thanks for your reply but the code of sms sending is not working there are no errors but when i run it in emulator it force close no output and as i mentioned earlier that i have to send sms via my phone attached with the USB port so for that shoukd i have to access the libraries of the phone ?? thnks in advance please helpp !!!!